# Using ffmpeg with chunks of file

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to download a file as 100mb chunks and I need to convert this using ffmpeg and upload this file to dropbox.
The code I tried:

```
import os
import requests

#---snip---#

for chunk in r.iter_content(chunksize=chunksize):
  #chunksize is 100mb
  fp = open("a.mp4","wb")
  fp.write(chunk)
  fp.close()
  os.system("ffmpeg -i a.mp4 a.mkv")
  
  #code for uploading
```

The error is `moov atom is not found`

1.How can I convert file chunks with ffmpeg?

2.Can I convert without ever needing to save to `a.mp4`, like giving `chunk` directly to ffmpeg?

Ps: The problem occurs with file size greater than 100mb

Edit:

After converting the file is appended to file in dropbox

What I want:

- Sample.mp4 - 200mb
- Downloads file as chunks 100mb
- Converts the chunk
- Upload to drive (multipart)

Comment: did you later find a solution to this?

Comment: @Anthony I didn't, since moov atom is found in the start or end of the video. The second chunk onwards happened to be just binary data with no metadata. Hypothetically, if somehow you could attach the moov atom data to the chunks and process the chunks and remove the metadata from that chunks and append that to the first chunk, and hope that it works.